# Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, access-control, preflight

I'm trying to fetch quotes history from yahoo api:
[Yahoo Historical quotes](http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?&a=0&b=1&c=2011&d=3&e=17&f=2017&s=YHOO)

I encountered cross-origin error and I tried to resolve it by setting the correct xmlHttpRequest header. I have followed recommendation from other posts but no success.

I don't want to use Yahoo YQL, as it limits response to ~2 years quotes history.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         // console.log(this.responseText);
         console.log(this.getAllResponseHeaders())
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?&a=0&b=1&c=2011&d=3&e=17&f=2017&s=YHOO", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("cache-control" , "private");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description");
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can list down what are the recommendations that you have tried btw.